# Laravel 4 - User_detail Model

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `User` model which extends `Eloquent` which gets the data from the *users* table in my database.

The *users* table has the login details and a bunch of other data. Now I want to create a *user_details* table which has even more details about a user such as address and contact info.

Do I create another model class called `User_detail` and make this class extend the `User` class? I'm not sure how to collaborate the two models if that is the correct way of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use a one to many relation in your User model...

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many

In your User class...

```
public function details() {
    return $this->hasMany('UserDetail');
}
```

You would call it like...

```
foreach (User::find(1)->details as $row) {

}
```

Comment: Your link goes to one to one, but your example shows `hasMany`?

Comment: Should be `$this->belongsTo('User')` (Detail) and `$this->hasOne('Detail')` (User).